# Control console for C# .net program

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I'm running a C# .net program under mono on Unix and I'm looking to control or change the behavior of the program after it has started.

I'll write the new functions into the program so I just need to trigger them without restarting the program.

I'm thinking I could allow the program to accept messages such as SOAP but feel this might be insure. It might be better if I could control the program locally from a separate program but i'm unsure of where to start.

Is there a way to give instructions into the program after it has started without a separate program or if the separate program is the solution does anyone know where to start with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Through TCP: http://forums.trossenrobotics.com/tutorials/introduction-129/reading-and-writing-tcp-sockets-in-c-2325/

"Untested on mono" though...

Comment: How you'll do that? **"I'll write the new functions into the program"**

Comment: Do you mean that you want to send messages to your program to trigger existing behaviour, or that you want to inject new code into the program after it's started?

Comment: I mean than I would like to be able to trigger existing behavior within the program from an external source be that command line or a separate program. I haven't written the functions to be triggered yet as I'm still unsure of the triggering method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create some UI form into your app and you will be able to controll your app by using this UI. If it isn't using you can hide that form to tray.

Or you can use second app and send some messages to your first application by using sockets, for example.

Comment: The target program will be running on a Unix sever and will not have a UI to speak of.

Comment: I do like the socket idea though as we could go with separate app with a UI that's more user friendly than a command line interface or a perl script.

Answer (score 1):

The way this is usually done in Unix programs ([reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Handling-the-SIGHUP-Signal-in-Daemons)) is by sending the SIGHUP [signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#POSIX_signals), and letting the program interpret this as a command to reload its configuration file.

Sending a signal can be done from a terminal or script with the Unix `kill` command (which is named this way because the default signal is SIGTERM to request the process to shut down itself).

This is how you send SIGHUP to a process with a certain PID:

```
kill -HUP [pid]
```

You can use the mono [UnixSignal](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aMono.Unix.UnixSignal) class to handle these Unix signals in a .NET program. One way is to use `.WaitOne` to wait for the signal on a dedicated thread. Another way is by regularly polling `.IsSet` or `.Count`.

Comment: The signal stuff was an interesting read, that could be useful when not using a UI interface.